# What's necessary in order for release notes to appear for packages in TFS using Paket?

Tags: tfs, nuget, paket

I've checked both paket.template to make sure that the Release Notes have the correct format according to the [paket.template guide](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/template-files.html) and tried [pack.exe pack --release-notes](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/paket-pack.html) both without the desired result. That desired result would be release notes appearing with other details of the package in TFS (screenshot below).

[image]

Comment: Did you check the package after being packed (either using NuGet Package Explorer, or opening the nupkg as a zip, and looking at the nuspec file), to make sure it contains release notes? The [nuget docs show the nuspec has an element for release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/reference/nuspec#releasenotes) which is almost certainly what TFS is showing.

Comment: Yes, I did check that too. Will begin modifying Paket source next to see whether it's an issue with the .nupkg file generation.

Comment: It was a case of formatting the text correctly! :/